# Virtual machine sharing setup with Windows host and *nix guest that allows symlinks?

Tags: virtualbox, file-sharing, symbolic-link

I'm using VirtualBox (and have tried VMWare) on a Windows 7 host with an Ubuntu server guest. I've set up folder sharing in VirtualBox so that my Ubuntu server home dir is a mount of my Windows 7 home dir, so that I have access to the same files regardless of which OS I'm in.

The issue is that I can't create symlinks inside that shared folder, which is problematic as some software I use requires it (eg. RVM). A similar setup in VMWare led to the same results. Is there any sharing setup that would allow creating symbolic links in the *nix guest? I've tried Samba, but no still no go.

Answer (score 1):

Linux [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) are not ordinary files.  They are a unique type of file supported by Linux filesystems.  Linux symbolic links are not supported by Windows filesystems (FAT32, NTFS, etc.).  VirtualBox mounts the Windows host's shared folders using the [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifs) (aka SMB) protocol.  That protocol also does not support Linux symbolic links.  If the host and the guest were both Linux machines, then this would work.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought. Didn't know VirtualBox used CIFS.

Answer (score 0):

In vmware vmx file you can try to add.

sharedFolder0.followSymlinks = "TRUE"

To enable the symlink following.

Not used your specific host/guest combo so I am uncertain if it works for you, and I am not sure whether it requires workstation. Worth trying at least.

Comment: You need to shut down the vm before modifying the configuration file.